# What is the volume of a right triangular pyramid translated into the 4th dimension?

Tags: triangles, volume

I've been doing calculations on my own, just messing around, with infinite series and their respective geometries. I don't actually know enough to do this correctly but I've been led to believe that the next infinite series that I'm working on would be equivalent to the volume of the space of a right triangular pyramid that is shifted or translated (I don't know the proper term) into the $4$th dimension.

So for example. I translated the area of a right triangle into the third dimension by taking 3 right triangles and lining them up with one another to make a right triangular pyramid. The resulting volume of this is $$\frac{1}{6}\times\text{Area of Base}\times \text{Height of Pyramid}$$

So if you took $4$ right triangular pyramids and matched them up to one another four times in the $4$th dimension, what would the resulting volume be?

I would expect it to be after the pattern of the 4th dimensional cube but just a fraction of it like: $$\frac{wxyz}{n}$$

Basically I need to know what fraction of the $4$th dimensional cube would the volume contain if it was entirely constructed from right triangles that are exactly half of the squares area.

Comment: I expect the fraction to be 1/24 but I need to be certain. If it is 1/24 then I will be very happy. Someone please verify this for me! It's killing me.

Comment: It is indeed $1/n!$ for $n$ dimensions.

Comment: AMAZING! Think about how this matches to Euler's number and it's calculation! I've just discovered how to calculate all infinite series through geometry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $3$ dimensions, the formula is $1/3$ the area of the base times the height.  I'm not sure you got $1/6.$  Perhaps, you mean $1/6$ a rectangular box enclosing the pyramid. That is, $x$ is one side of the triangular base, $y$ is the height of the triangle, $z$ is the height of the pyramid.

In $4$ dimensions, the volume of a pyramid is $1/4$ times the $3-$dimensional  volume of the base, or $xyzw/24$ if you've chosen $x,y,z,w$ to represent the sides of a rectangular box enclosing the pyramid in the same way as in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: Look up the volume of a RIGHT triangular pyramid. It is 1/6 not 1/3 for that.

Comment: @ketenks Read what I wrote.

Comment: OH! so you are saying it is 1/4 of the 1/6!!! So it is 1/24!! That's exactly what I needed it to be too! then this the answer for sure. are you sure this is right?

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure.  You can look at the formula for the [volume of a simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume)  A simplex in the $n-$dimensional analogue of a triangle.  I realize you may not understand the formula, but you see the ${1\over n!}$ on the right hand side, and the rest of the formula (the determinant) give the volume of a rectangular n-dimensional box.

Comment: Excellent! Just think about how that matches Euler's number for a minute! That's exactly what I needed to know. This is the fundamental calculation of Euler's number.